# How do I run a local ruby gem with dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems

New to ruby so this is probably a basic question.  I'm trying to run this ruby script: https://github.com/goncaloborrega/TrelloToAsana and I cloned the files locally and ran `ruby exportTrelloToAsana.rb` which gave an error `require': cannot load such file -- trello (LoadError)`

I also tried running `gem install` in the local folder where I cloned the files to.

How do I run/build that gem script with all it's dependencies?

Normally I just run gem install for remote gems but not sure how to do it when the files are local.

Comment: Are you saying you ran `gem install -i dir` on all the dependencies, including ruby-trello, to install them to a local directory?

Comment: Project contains `Gemfile`, a dependencies specification file for [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) tool. You may use it to automatically install dependencies or you may do it manually, of course.

Comment: how do I install the dependencies - i tried gem install with and without the -i dir command and I get the error ` Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the dependencies listed in the script installed.

```
require "rubygems"
require 'trello'
require 'asana'
require 'yaml'
```

For each gem (library):

```
gem install ruby-trello
gem install asana
...
```

Comment: when installing ruby-trello I get error `checking for main() in -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***`

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: mac... i did the install with `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install asana
` and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not a gem. This is a repository for ruby script, which is inside the `exportTrelloToAsana.rb` file. 
You just need to add this file to your project and start using it.